# unity project settings reset after git clone

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project with the proper git settings (asset serialization -> force text and visible meta files) pushed to github.

- All meta files are present
- All project settings files are present
- Using the same editor version

But - project was originally on windows. The git clone is on Mac.

There are some 3rd party packages not present - I plan to install those after git clone.

I cloned the repo, and added to unity-hub (and installed the correct editor version).

When I open the project, though, the project settings are wrong.
My custom physics layers are missing. I also had the color space set to linear but it's set to gamma after git clone.

Not sure why the project settings are not loading properly. The unity project settings files are present in the file system under the project folder.

I do have some errors in the console. Is this preventing the project from loading the settings properly?
Errors are things like:

```
Failed to load '/Users/username/Desktop/stuff/unity-project/Assets/Gaia User Data/Sessions/GS-20230502 - 230047/Gaia Lighting Settings.asset'. File may be corrupted or was serialized with a newer version of Unity.
```

Do errors like this cause the project settings from being loaded properly?

gitIgnore is copied from github's unity git-ignore template:

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore
#
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/[Ll]ogs/
/[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/
/Assets/GIT-IGNORE-3rd-party-assets/
/Assets/3rd-party-assets/BOXOPHOBIC/The\ Vegetation\ Engine/Demo/
/Assets/3rd-party-assets/GPUInstancer/Demos/
/Assets/3rd-party-assets/HighlightPlus/Demo/


# MemoryCaptures can get excessive in size.
# They also could contain extremely sensitive data
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Recordings can get excessive in size
/[Rr]ecordings/

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
/[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.aab
*.unitypackage
*.app

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# Packed Addressables
/[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*

# Temporary auto-generated Android Assets
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa.meta
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa/*

# Windows thumbnail cache files
Thumbs.db
Thumbs.db:encryptable
ehthumbs.db
ehthumbs_vista.db

# Dump file
*.stackdump

# Folder config file
[Dd]esktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Windows Installer files
*.cab
*.msi
*.msix
*.msm
*.msp

# Windows shortcuts
*.lnk
```

I've included the following in git:

- Assets folder
- Project Settings folder
- Packages folder
- And of course gitignore and gitAttributes files

Not sure if I'm missing something - any help is appreciated

Comment: _"I do have some errors in the console"_ what errors?

Comment: which folders in your project folder did you include, and maybe importantly didnt include

Comment: What does you `,gitignore` file look like?

Comment: this helped: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/FPSSample/issues/59#issuecomment-482557352

Comment: Yeah, missing the lfs stuff would do it.

Comment: I think the project settings are not pushed as sometimes unity doesn't save some files properly, yu need to manually save them. Does the mentioned project settings present (pushed) in your git client ?

Comment: @sujoybyte project settings are on github. I was missing the git lfs pull

Answer (score 1):

I had to run `git lfs pull` to pull the large file storage files. things are working properly now.

found the answer here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/FPSSample/issues/59#issuecomment-482557352